# JS saying that form is not defined (FireFox 4.0)

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code

```
<form name='logOut' id="logOut" action="/ProCommerce/index.php" method="post">
        <input name="logMeOut" type="hidden" value="1">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+shift+l', function(){
            showDiv('loginDiv');
        });
        $(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+shift+o', function(){
            logOut.submit();
        });
    </script>
```

It works great in Chrome and IE, but in FireFox I always get : Error: logOut is not defined
Source File: http://localhost/ProCommerce/index.php?action=home
Line: 416

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accessing DOM element by its id directly from global window object is only supported in IE, so in firefox you would probably do `document.getElementById('logOut').submit()` or `$('#logOut').submit()`

Comment: Just to add that to use $('#logOut').submit(); you will require the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected $("#logOut").submit();